# Ionic IOS app's Signal-R events are not updating (realtime) when the app moved to background?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, signalr, capacitor

I'm developing an sms based Ionic IOS app. And we are using Signal-R events to update the app in real-time. In Android, the app is updating real-time when it's opened and even in the background. But in the IOS app, it's not working when the app is in the background.
(This is a capacitor ionic app)

What may be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Capacitor background task [plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/v2/apis/background-task). Also make sure to read the guidelines. Apple currently allows a maximum of 30 seconds after an app has closed to run any bg task, so you have minimal time.